# Mac OS: Password keeper sofware?

Tags: macos, software-rec, password-management

Looking for some Password Manager solution which can also sync with server or export so I can use it on other PC. Add notes, generate password.. Something like Password Agent for windows. Not a keychain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password) do what you are looking for?

Comment: Something like that. Any other options?

Comment: That's on lifehackers top 10 favorite mac apps list.

Answer (score 3):

I'm very happy with [KeePassX](http://www.keepassx.org/start/) (cross-platform) on a [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) account (for syncing across machines)

Comment: Oh, that sounds nice

Comment: It's free, which is good. Anything else?

Comment: Cross-platform, can generate passwords, supports notes, can organise passwords hierarchically with custom icons, handy security features like clearing clipboard and locking application on minimise.

Comment: Is it stable on Mac?

Comment: I haven't tried it on a Mac but I've had zero issues with it on Win XP/Vista/7 and Ubuntu, while syncing across those platforms using Dropbox.

Comment: It's excellent on the Mac - don't leave home without it.

Comment: I can appreciate KeePassX's attractive cost, but 1Password's browser integration, features, and ease of use are definitely worth the paltry $40.  They're coming out with a Windows port too, and I easily sync my database across multiple computers with Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

Lastpass.com seems pretty neat. They also have client apps for almost every device imaginable (including Blackberry).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Password Gorilla (free, open source) on my Macs and Password Safe on my PC's. Syncing via Dropbox. The Gorilla is unfortunately quite slow, while the Safe is quick as a bunny. Both have been very stable for me, though.

Comment: There are also more suggestions (and links to other similar questions) here: http://superuser.com/questions/121663/good-tools-for-managing-many-usernames-and-passwords/121672#121672

Answer (score 0):

[Clipperz](https://www.clipperz.com) works well on any platform as it's web based.